# How to configure Jaeger data source in Grafana properly?

Tags: grafana, jaeger

I would like to configure Jaeger data source in Grafana. I have Loki, Jaeger, Grafana installed in Kubernetes cluster. All services are up and running. Then, I navigate to Grafana to set up a new data source for Jaeger. Specify Jaeger url (`http://jaeger-tracing-query.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:16687`), click on [Save & test] button and the *'Data source connected, but no services received. Verify that Jaeger is configured properly.'* error message is shown. If I navigate to Jaeger UI, I can clearly see 2 services.

Could you please guide me on what is probably missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I was scratching my head over this issue.

All the documents say you need to connet to `{pod}.{namespace}:{port}`

I noticed if you go to the Jaeger UI it's querying for the services on this endpoint

`http://localhost:16686/jaeger/api/services`

[image]

So I went back to Grafana and set the URL to `http://jaeger-query:16686/jaeger`

[image]

Comment: it is working for me. For cluster service mapping to 80, you can put to grafana datasource like this: http://jaeger.<namespace>/jaeger

Answer (score 0):

16687 is admin port. Use port 80 to configure the data source in grafana.

it should be like jaeger-tracing-query.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:80

Answer (score -1):

I found my UI was querying `http://localhost:16686/jaeger/ui/api/services`, changing the data source URL in grafana to `http://localhost:16686/jaeger/ui` fixed it for me.